# Can JavaScript run commands on cmd.exe?

Tags: javascript, cmd

Can a JavaScript file run a command to cmd.exe? e.g.

```
echo Hello>>text.txt
```

I ask because I am creating a Discord bot with JavaScript and I want the bot to log certain things in a text file. Maybe there is a better method of this, but I obviously don't know about it. I'm dipping in to things that I never have before, so please tolerate my cluelessness. I am using Node.js and the Discord.js library, if that information is vital.

Comment: This seems rather indirect. Just use file system objects (i.e., https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) or a logging library to write to a file instead.

Comment: yes, look into "childProcess" https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
  console.log("whatever");
```

If you want to store the console output to a file just run this before:

```
 const fs = require("fs");
 process.stdout.pipe( fs.createWriteStream("text.txt", {flags:"r+"}));
```